# Mysql Query to fetch data of shared posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

DB Schema is given below. how can i fetch posts plus shared posts of users like Facebook. in Facebook wall the we can see original posts and the posts user shared. how can i actively get the posts. records could be in millions. 
i have tried using joining two tables but i am unable to identify the shared posts.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    post_shares
    INNER JOIN posts 
        ON (post_shares.post_id = posts.id);
```

[image: DB Schema]

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried using joining two tables but i am unable to actually build the logic to fetch the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, description from post where user_id = 'xyz'
union
select id, description from post p, post_shares ps where p.id = ps.post_id and ps.user_id = 'xyz'
```

Top part of the query will give you posts for user 'xyz' and second part will give you posts that the user shared.